# Removing top and bottom lines on a list on iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

I have an app for iPad that uses a navigation list, and another list to display items. The items list always displays a top and bottom lines, even when no items are there.

[image]

I have tried `.listStyle(.plain)` and `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` but nothing helps.
Anyone has any idea how to remove those lines? I can't find anything on Apple's documentation or here at SO.

Thanks.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Set<Int> = [0]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: self.$selection) {
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemsList(wantStarred: 0)) {
                    Label("All Items", systemImage: "chart.bar.doc.horizontal").tag(0)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemsList(wantStarred: 1)) {
                    Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star.fill")
                }
                
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 150, idealWidth: 150, maxHeight: .infinity)

            ItemsList(wantStarred: 0)
        }
    }
    
}


struct ItemsList: View {
    @State var wantStarred: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
           //...
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        .overlay {
            if items.count == 0 {
                Text("Create a new item.").fontWeight(.light)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you might could wrap the list in an if statement so it doesn't show if empty

Comment: Thanks, but the lines also show when the list has content. Top and bottom lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listRowSeparator modifier should be *inside* list

```
    List {
       Text("")
          .listRowSeparator(.hidden) // << like here !!
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5